# exclude in maven-jarsigner-plugin doesn't work

Tags: maven, jarsigner, maven-jarsigner-plugin

I have configured the jar signer plugin in my Project

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sign</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sign</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*-javadoc.jar</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*-sources.jar</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <keystore>${project.basedir}\security\keystore.jks</keystore>
                <alias>mydomain</alias>
                <storepass>changeit</storepass>
                <keypass>changeit</keypass>
            </configuration>
```

Because my Project also generate a javadoc and a sources jar which should not be signed, i try to exclude it. But it seems not working. If i look into my jar files, thay are signed. Also if i take a look into the maven Output i can see that the jar signer is called for the sources and javadoc jar.

I can see, that the configuration is consumed by maven:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jarsigner-plugin:1.4:sign' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) alias = mydomain
[DEBUG]   (f) arguments = []
[DEBUG]   (f) excludes = [**/*-javadoc.jar, **/*-sources.jar]
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the exclution section?

Comment: @Downvoter please explain

Comment: Why you Downvoters do not explain why. It would be very helpful to improve the question

Comment: @Downvoter: Thanks again

Comment: Re _"what is wrong with the exclution section?"_, is it possibly because you had not specified the **archiveDirectory** parameter? [From the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jarsigner-plugin/sign-mojo.html) for the **excludes** parameter: _"The patterns must be relative to the directory given by the parameter **archiveDirectory**"_. The **excludeClassifiers** parameter worked for you because it doesn't care about the **archiveDirectory**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use the [excludeClassifiers](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jarsigner-plugin/sign-mojo.html)

```xml
<excludeClassifiers>
  <excludeClassifier>javadoc</excludeClassifier>
  <excludeClassifier>sources</excludeClassifier>
</excludeClassifiers>
```

instead of your excludes.

Furthermore I would recommand to prevent using back slashes in a Maven pom.

Comment: It works for me. Thanks a lot. But why exclude does not work?